# p- and n- contact metal difference

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics, electronics, metals

I'm reading an article about some electronic components and the authors specify that they used p- and n- contact metals, but without giving details about those metals, or what material are they really.

So is there some difference between metals that would normally be connected to an n and p semiconductors? What elements/alloys are we talking about?

Comment: Depends on the semiconductor in question. For silicon it doesn’t matter. For many III-V materials it matters a lot.

Comment: @JonCuster that's intriguing. Do you mean the same thing as in the answer from user "engineer" or do you mean something extra?

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. With silicon, it happily makes an ohmic, metallurgical junction, generally a silicide (silicon-metal alloy). With a III-V, there just aren’t ternary metallic alloys that make an ohmic contact - the Ga and As (for example) have different alloy phase diagrams. So you are stuck with the Schottky contacts and then each one has to be different to match to the dopant levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's important to understand the actual problem. A contact between a metal and a semiconductor is of Schottky type. That means there is a jump in the electronic band profile, which carriers can easily pass in one direction but not in the other. So these contacts lead to rectifying behavior.

For a device, you usually want ohmic contacts. In reality that means quasi-ohmic contacts, which you can achieve, when reducing the Schottky barrier height to a minimum - ideally to 0.

Now what you can do, and this is where different contact materials come into play, is that you match the work function of the metal with the band edge of the semiconductor. In an n-type contact, you would try to align the work function of the metal with the conduction band edge of the semiconductor, so electrons can pass in either direction. Technically, they still need to overcome the Schottky barrier in one direction, but it's kept at a minimum. Conversely, you would try to align the work function of the contact material with the valence band edge for p-type contacts, so holes can travel without observing a barrier. This also means that there can not really be a contact material that works for both types.

In general, you would mix a noble metal with something that typically also acts as n- or p-type dopant for the semiconductor to facilitate a good contact.

For III-V semiconductors, you could either use Sn/Au, Ge/Au or more complex structures that may also contain diffusion barriers as n-type contacts. Good p-type contacts would be Zn/Au, Cr/Au, sometimes Pt. As always, there are advantages and disadvantages. Zn tends to diffuse a lot and can degrage. Cr and Pt require higher temperatures for evaporation or higher powers during sputter deposition, which may damage photo-resist masks.